# jQuery prepopulate and format a text field

Tags: jquery

This is confusing me.

I have a PHP app with a text field, the client wants the field to be prepopulated with 896- and followed by user input of only five numeric values, so it would be like 896-12569.
I

I would like to do this in jQuery, is this possible, if so how?

Comment: this looks like you need to use mask: `$('#date').mask('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing this using CSS, but here is a jQuery solution:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var prefix = '896-';
  var value = this.value.replace(prefix, '').replace(/[^\d]/, '').substr(0, 5);
  this.value = prefix + value;
}).keyup(); // trigger the keyup event, so that the field is populated at load
```

Obviously swap `input` for the relevant selector, and add events as necessary (this example only works on the `keyup` event).

---

#### Edit

Having looked at the code again, I noticed there's a small bug (press <kbd>backspace</kbd> once), ths `prefix` gets added again (this is because it isn't removed from the `input` because it no longer matches), a quick fix would be to just always replace the first 4 characters of the input:

```
var value = this.value.replace(this.value.substr(0, 4), '').replace(/[^\d]/, '').substr(0, 5);
```

Comment: billyonecan - this is so close, the only thing though, I want the 896-to immediately be in the field when the form is open, then when user starts typing, their 5 digits are just added to the end of the 896-

Comment: Just trigger the `keyup()` after binding it

Comment: Better, I think this is better> onclick/onfocus of the field, the 896- appears, but when I try to add the numeric mask I either get an error or the 896 is removed.

Comment: Not sure I follow - actually I am positive I don't follow. :)

Comment: THAT IS CRAZY COOL - THanks!!!!!!  I won't even share how much code I had added to attempt this effect.

Comment: @user1176783 noticed there was a small bug with the code, check my edit, should be good now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this.

Simply put the `896-` outside the input field and style it to look normal

```
<div class="controls">
    896-<input type="text" name="postfix" class="prefixed-input" />
</div>
```

Then, in PHP you can prefix the 896- to the number before you store it.

See an example on [Bootstraps website](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms). Under the "Extending form controls" heading.